# How to track user activity in angular 5?

Tags: angular, tracking, user-activity

I have recently started working on angular 5.I want to track each activity/event of user using a common functionality.
I have done this in angularJs by using **angular-activity-monitor** but don't know how do the same in angular 5, 
Can anyone have an idea about it ?

Comment: If you ask for a library recommendation, this is off-topic. If you ask how to "track the activity of a user", it's unclear: you need to define "track" and "activity".

Answer (score 0):

Currently working on building out an Angular 7.1 app. But I have been using `@ng-idle/core` since Angular 4. It wasn't too difficult to setup.

But I am now looking to see if there are any comparable products out there.